# Null field in elasticsearch need to be replaced

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

How can i replace the `"build_duration" : "null",` with value `21600000` in elasticsearch?

**DevTools > Console**

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "build_duration": "null" 
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 9.658761,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "40324749",
        "_score" : 9.658761,
        "_source" : {
        "build_duration" : "null",
        "build_end_time" : "2021-05-20 04:00:36",
        "build_requester" : "daniel.su",
        "build_site" : "POL",
        "build_id" : "40324749",
        "@version" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below query able to replace the filed value.

```
  POST /myindex/_update/mydocid
    {
        "doc" : {
            "build_duration": "21600000"
        }
    }
```